# Using a Macro to insert multiple rows after a change in recordset?

Tags: vba, excel

This is an inherited code, and I am no expert in VBA, in fact -- I've never used it. After toying around for a bit I felt that maybe someone could offer some much needed help.

Currently this VBA will add a row when there is a change in columnd D. This works fine, all I'm looking to augment is the number of rows inserted. Lets say instead of 1, I'd like 4 rows inserted. Where in the code would I make these chanegs?

```
Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()

Dim lRow As Long

' Break line at USD / Local

For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
If Cells(lRow, "D") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "D") Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
Next lRow
```

I am assuming it would have to be somehwere in the `Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert` but everything I try seems to not work.

If you could also explain why what you suggested worked, that would also be helpful so I no longer need to rely on the community. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fastest way:

```
Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()

    Dim lRow As Long

    ' Break line at USD / Local

    For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(lRow, "D") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "D") Then
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a compile error when running this code. 'Next without For' ... Do I need to add an additional 'For' for every row I'm attemtping to insert?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the *End If*  This should work for you.

Comment: Works perfect. Did I not need to have an End If initially because I only specified one clause in my If statement prior to the code change?

Comment: It's because it was a *one-liner* if statement.  If your if statement spans multiple lines, then you need the "End If"